# Dot a video file but still shows up in video gallery

Tags: 8.0-oreo

I used to be able to hide video files in video gallery on my Samsung by adding a door in front of the filename.  After I change to Huawei phone, these files with dot in front just shows up like it is is not hidden anymore. Is there a change in hidden hide usage in android?

Comment: do you want to hide individual files or the entire folder contents?

Comment: Dot before a **folder** hides the folder. `.nomedia` **within** a folder hides the files contained in it from media scanner